# NullPointerException: LinearLayout is Null

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-linearlayout

Please have a look at the following code

```
private class OpenFileEvent implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            LinearLayout openFileDialogView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.open_file_dialog);

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Dialog openFileDialog = new Dialog(VoiceNotes.this);
            openFileDialog.setTitle("Open File");
            openFileDialog.setContentView(R.layout.open_dialog);


            //First, list all the available Files
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Voice/Notes/");
            File file = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath());

            File[] fileNameList = file.listFiles();


            if(fileNameList != null && fileNameList.length>0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<fileNameList.length;i++)
                {
                    //Get the sub views first
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    View openThisFileView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.open_dialog_file, null);      
                    Button openThisFileButton = (Button)openThisFileView.findViewById(R.id.open_this_file_button);
                    Button appendThisFileButton = (Button)openThisFileView.findViewById(R.id.append_note_this_file);
                    TextView openThisFileNameTxt = (TextView)openThisFileView.findViewById(R.id.open_this_file_name);

                    //Set the Text
                    openThisFileNameTxt.setText(fileNameList[i].getName());

                    //Set the Listeners


                    //Add the View
                    openFileDialogView.addView(openThisFileView);

                }
            }
            //Show the Dialog
            openFileDialog.show();

        }

    }
```

As soon as this code in running, I get the following error message, which is `NullPointerException`

```
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.x.xxx.VoiceNotes$OpenFileEvent.onClick(VoiceNotes.java:227)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-18 16:24:20.832: E/AndroidRuntime(1019):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is targetting to here

```
openFileDialogView.addView(openThisFileView);
```

Since it says that `LinearLayout` is null, here is the XML file where that layout belongs to.

**open_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/open_file_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#ffffff">

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the same layout which acts as the Content View for the `Dialog`.

Why I think that `LinearLayout` is null, and not the layout which got inflated inside the class? Because the below code also generated `NullPointerException`

```
openFileDialogView.addView(new Button(Notes.this));
```

Why I am getting this error?

Comment: Can you please highlight which line is `227` ?

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see if VoiceNotes contains what you think it should?  It's not defined in the scope of the code snip you provided so I can't speculate much about it.

Comment: You should probably put all of this code in its own class that extends `DialogFragment`. It will be much better for you in the long run.

Comment: @inner_class7: Thanks for the suggestion.I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
LinearLayout openFileDialogView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.open_file_dialog);
```

Here `findViewById()` attempts to find the specified view in the activity's view hierarchy (as set by `setContentView()` but you're inflating a layout with that id only later on. `findViewById()` returns `null` and attempting to invoke a method on `null` causes NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving this line

```
 LinearLayout openFileDialogView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.open_file_dialog);
```

after

```
openFileDialog.setContentView(R.layout.open_dialog);
```

in your code.